how to correct convert Timestamp to Instant with UTC time zone?
I have a problem when i get a data from DB
I get data like this TIMESTAMP TIME = 2024-05-15 15:12:44.0 - Timestamp SQL (package) type
After i convert to Instant i have offset -3 hours
Like this INSTANT TIME = 2024-05-15T12:12:44Z
Here is my example of code
package ru.goldenage.map.repository.postgres.impl;


import ru.goldenage.map.entity.postgres.CalculatedCar;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;

@Slf4j
@Repository
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CarDAOImpl {
    
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate postgresTemplate;
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<CalculatedCar> getCalculatedCarsBy(String minutes) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT tmi.p_id                                                   AS id,"
        + "tmi.p_park_id                                                                AS parkId, "
        + "tmi.p_gosnumber                                                              AS gosnumber,"
        + "tmi.p_park_name                                                              AS parkName,"
        + "taotr.p_lon                                                                  AS lon,"
        + "taotr.p_lat                                                                  AS lat,"
        + "p_azimuth                                                                    AS vector,"
        + "p_speed                                                                      AS speed,"
        + "tmi.p_mark_name                                                              AS markName,"
        + "tmi.p_mark_id                                                                AS markId,"
        + "tmi.p_transport_type                                                         AS TT_Title,"
        + "mt.p_group_id                                                                AS groupTransportType,"
        + "mt.p_title                                                                   AS titleTransportType,"
        + "org.p_title                                                                  AS organization,"
        + "taotr.p_time                                                                 AS time,"
        + "p_kilometers                                                                 AS kilometers,"
        + "coalesce(substring(tum.p_name from 0 for position(' км' in tum.p_name)), '') AS road_name,"
        + "coalesce(tmi.p_navigator, '-')                                               AS stationNum,"
        + "tmi.p_machine_type "
        + "FROM t_machine_info AS tmi "
          + "LEFT JOIN t_machine_type AS mt on tmi.p_machine_type = mt.p_id "
          + "LEFT JOIN t_organization AS org on tmi.p_organization = org.p_id, "
      + "(SELECT * FROM t_auto_on_the_roads "
       + "WHERE p_id in (SELECT max(p_id) FROM t_auto_on_the_roads "
                      + "WHERE p_time >= (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') - (?1 * CAST('1 minutes' AS interval)) "
                      + "GROUP BY p_id_auto)) AS taotr "
          + "LEFT JOIN t_unit_members AS tum ON tum.p_id = taotr.p_name_road "
 + "WHERE taotr.p_id_auto = tmi.p_id;";

       List<Object[]> resultList = em.createNativeQuery(sql)
                                     .setParameter(1, Integer.parseInt(minutes))
                                     .getResultList();

      List<CalculatedCar> calculatedCars = new ArrayList<>(resultList.size());

      resultList.forEach(result -> {
             BigDecimal id = (BigDecimal)result[0];
             Integer parkId = (Integer)result[1]; 
             String gosNumber = (String) result[2];
             String parkName = (String) result[3];
             Double lon = (Double) result[4];
             Double lat = (Double) result[5];
             Integer vector = (Integer) result[6];
             Integer speed = (Integer) result[7];
             String markName = (String) result[8];
             Integer markId = (Integer) result[9];
             String title = (String) result[10];
             BigDecimal groupTransportType = (BigDecimal) result[11];
             String titleTransportType = (String) result[12];
             String organization = (String) result[13];
             Timestamp tmp = (Timestamp) result[14];
             System.out.println("TIMESTAMP TIME = " + tmp);
             Instant timeUTC = tmp.toInstant();
             System.out.println("INSTANT TIME = " + timeUTC);
             String kilometers = (String) result[15];
             String roadName = (String) result[16];
             String stationNum = (String) result[17];
             BigDecimal machineType = (BigDecimal) result[18];

             CalculatedCar car = CalculatedCar
                                    .builder()
                                    .id(id)
                                    .parkId(parkId)
                                    .gosnumber(gosNumber)
                                    .parkName(parkName)
                                    .lon(lon)
                                    .lat(lat)
                                    .vector(vector)
                                    .speed(speed)
                                    .markName(markName)
                                    .markId(markId)
                                    .TTTitle(title)
                                    .groupTransportType(groupTransportType)
                                    .titleTransportType(titleTransportType)
                                    .organization(organization)
                                    .timeUTC(timeUTC)
                                    .kilometers(kilometers)
                                    .roadName(roadName)
                                    .stationNum(stationNum)
                                    .machineType(machineType)
                                    .build();
             calculatedCars.add(car);
        });

      return calculatedCars;
    }
}


the conversion happens in this part of the code
  Timestamp tmp = (Timestamp) result[14];
  System.out.println("TIMESTAMP TIME = " + tmp);
  Instant timeUTC = tmp.toInstant();
  System.out.println("INSTANT TIME = " + timeUTC);

I expecting time with UTC date time without changes 2024-05-15 15:12:44.0 because in DB i write a UTC time already, but type in DB Postgres in this table have a Timestamp without time zone.
Java 11 version. Spring 2.1.2 RELEASE. Postgres 9.6.15.

Java 11 version

Spring 2.1.2 REALESE
Postgres 9.6.15

the conversion happens in this part of the code It's 'converted' as that's what happens when you print [toString()] a Timestamp. That confusing behaviour is one of several reasons why you shouldn't be using it. tmp.getTime() should show the same value as timeUTC.toEpochMilli()

No, no necessary.Also when they are transferred to the front via json.

Sorry, I don't understand your comment

By the way, a tip: text blocks. And also by the way, Postgres 9 reached end-of-life long ago, plus you are not even using the last update of Postgres 9.

What exactly is the data type of your column in Postgres?

Way too much code. Strip down to absolute minimum needed to demonstrate your issue. MCVE

You have provided too much code and not enough information to diagnose your problem. But I can tell you that if you deviate from the following items, you will run into trouble.
(I do not use Spring, so I refer here to straight JDBC.)

Stop using legacy date-time classes in Java. Use only the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.
To represent a moment in Java, a point on the timeline, use only these classes: Instant, OffsetDateTime, and ZonedDateTime.
To represent a moment in Postgres, use only a column of type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. Notice the WITH, not WITHOUT.
Know that those SQL standard names "WITH TIME ZONE"/"WITHOUT TIME ZONE" are misnomers — the authors of the SQL standard did not understand date-time handling, so they said "time zone" where they actually meant "offset from UTC". Accordingly:

Know Postgres always stores values in a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC).
Pass a moment to/from Postgres TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column using OffsetDateTime class.


Use PreparedStatement#setObject and ResultSet#getObject to exchange date-time values between the database and Java.

You said:

I get data like this TIMESTAMP TIME = 2024-05-15 15:12:44.0

That value lacks an indicator of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. So that value is inherently ambiguous. We do not know if it refers to 3 PM in Tokyo, Toulouse, or Toledo.
I suspect you either used the wrong column type in your database as discussed above, or you mangled the value after retrieval.
Retrieve a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value from Postgres:
String sql = "SELECT when_ from some_table_ ;" ;
…
OffsetDateTime when = myResultSet.getObject( 1 , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;

Adjust to a time zone.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Moscow" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = when.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;

You said:

2024-05-15 15:12:44.0 - Timestamp SQL (package) type After i convert to Instant i have offset -3 hours Like this INSTANT TIME = 2024-05-15T12:12:44Z

Firstly, stop using the terribly flawed legacy classes such as java.sql.Timestamp. Use only java.time classes.
Understand that Moscow time on that date is three hours behind UTC. So 3 PM on that date in Moscow time zone is the very same moment as noon in UTC — two ways of looking at the same point on the timeline.
The java.time.Instant class represents a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. (Exactly like TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE in both Postgres and the SQL standard.)
For example, given our code seen above in this Answer:
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from time zone to UTC (offset of zero). 


I expecting time with UTC date time without changes 2024-05-15 15:12:44.0 because in DB i write a UTC time already,

Either:

You are using wrong data types. For a moment, use only TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE in Postgres, and use only OffsetDateTime in your JDBC code.
Your code or framework(s) are mangling intermediate values.


I don't want to use a Timestamp but my current version of Spring Data retrive data in Timestamp type.

I try to use JDBC but when i have a SQL function, i use Timestamp from SQL and no have a result.

For addwords - this code from work project and change dependecies or change methods have a conflicts in a team
